# DISPLAY all tables from SQL database

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do i make it work?

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT TABLE_NAME  FROM
    databasename.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES);
```

Comment: Alias your derived table. *Why* are  you using a derived table at all though? Also, why use `SELECT *` when your derived table only has *one* column, `TABLE_NAME`?

Comment: I'm not crazy about the duplicate because the highly-voted and accepted answer uses less optimal and even deprecated methods.

Comment: I want to display all tables listed on
TABLE_NAME
I'm trying to do something like that
SELECT *FROM (all tables listed in the column of the other select)

Comment: But i guess i will just look in each of them manually

Comment: `I actually want the tables...`  Do you mean you want to query for the table definitions themselves and not just the table names?

Comment: I wanted was to display the actual table in the select not just make i don't know 30 selects at once but since no one understood what was asking i'll just do it in a hard way

Comment: If I understand your last comment, you want to select the data from each of the tables all at once in a single select?  That is never going to work.  SQL just doesn't work that way.  All results in a single SELECT statement have to fit within the same schema.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest query is:

```
SELECT name FROM [databasename].sys.tables;
```

But the better query is to take schema into account:

```
SELECT [schema] = s.name,
       [table]  = t.name
FROM [databasename].sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN [databasename].sys.schemas AS s
  ON t.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id];
```

You want to add a filter to prevent replication or diagram objects that you didn't create, e.g.

```
WHERE t.is_ms_shipped = 0;
```

If you're actually trying to say "I want all the data from all the tables" well, you'll need dynamic SQL for that, and I hope your tables aren't big.

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'';

SELECT @sql += N'SELECT ' + char(39) + ts + char(39) + ';
  SELECT * FROM ' + ts + N';'
FROM 
(
  SELECT ts = QUOTENAME(s.name) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(t.name)
    FROM sys.tables AS t
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
    ON t.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
    WHERE t.is_ms_shipped = 0
) AS x

PRINT @sql;
-- EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```

I would only use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` if I really needed metadata queries that were limited in scope because they need to work on multiple platforms. See [this blog post](https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information_schema-views) for more info.